# Apache POI: changing CellType causes IllegalStateException

Tags: java, apache-poi, illegalstateexception

Why is it illegal to change cell type in Apache POI? The code bellow causes `IllegalStateException: Cannot get a error value from a numeric cell`.

```java
Cell mycell = myrow.createCell(0);

// Make it numeric by default.
mycell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);

if (someCondition) {        
  mycell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING); // IllegalStateException
}
```

Is there perhaps a way around this problem (as in without introducing additional logic)?

Comment: Why not set the cell type when you create the cell? `myrow.createCell(0, cellType)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fixed it. After replacing the streaming version (`org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook`) with the non-streaming one (`org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook`) the exception was gone. I'm okay with XSSFWorkbook since I'm filling XLSX with only a couple of lines.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure this is avoiding your "without additional logic" but here goes:

```
Cell mycell = myrow.createCell(0);

// Make it numeric by default.
int cellType = Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC;

if (someCondition) {        
  cellType = Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING;
}

mycell.setCellType(cellType);
```

The Javadoc does not state why it would throw an `IllegalStateException` so I would just avoid it (by doing the above) or go digging in the sourcecode.